# How to include referenced entries in Contentstack JS API response

Tags: javascript, api, content-management-system, headless

I have a contentstack API call that looks like the following:

```
const Entry = Stack.ContentType('home').Entry("blt5e6d02158a314e4c");

Entry.fetch()
.then(function success(entry) {
    console.log(entry.toJSON());
})
```

That returns a response like this:

```
{
 "_version":13,
 "locale":"en-us",
 "uid":"blt5e6d02158a314e4c",
 "modular_blocks":[
    {
       "banner":{
          "title":"Test banner title",
          "background_image":null
       }
    },
    {
       "listing":{
          "title":"Test listing",
          "food_items":[
             {
                "uid":"blt3dc93d9d43186dd3",
                "_content_type_uid":"food_item"
             },
             {
                "uid":"blt9b3e1baeb2e3fe17",
                "_content_type_uid":"food_item"
             },
             {
                "uid":"bltf74ee44deee6501b",
                "_content_type_uid":"food_item"
             },
             {
                "uid":"blt3a164e1dcdf7fd8b",
                "_content_type_uid":"food_item"
             },
             {
                "uid":"blt9093f3bb9135e7b1",
                "_content_type_uid":"food_item"
             },
             {
                "uid":"blta1e533c66e8cf57a",
                "_content_type_uid":"food_item"
             },
             {
                "uid":"blt67728d24e4e704f2",
                "_content_type_uid":"food_item"
             },
             {
                "uid":"blt5af3ad110269ac72",
                "_content_type_uid":"food_item"
             },
             {
                "uid":"blt7a263ba68a1a39eb",
                "_content_type_uid":"food_item"
             },
             {
                "uid":"blt85cef2ca76051a6e",
                "_content_type_uid":"food_item"
             },
             {
                "uid":"blt857356711e1637a6",
                "_content_type_uid":"food_item"
             },
             {
                "uid":"blt446e027c9e069362",
                "_content_type_uid":"food_item"
             }
          ]
       }
    }
 ]
}
```

How can I INCLUDE the details of the "food_item" content entries in this response? Do I really need to query each one of those individually in order to get those details?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out, you have to use the .includeReference method on the Entry like this ->

```
Entry
.includeReference(['modular_blocks.listing.food_items'])
.fetch()
```